# No output from "New-SelfSignedCertificate" using -Subject option

Tags: security, certificate

I am using the New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet to create self-signed certificate as indicated by Microsoft documentation of that cmdlet:

```
Cert:\LocalMachine\My>New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Patti Fuller,OU=UserAccounts,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2","2.5.29.17={text}upn=pattifuller@contoso.com") -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

But there is no output created in “Cert:\LocalMachine\My” location?

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: In the command you specified `-CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"` which is different from and not the same as `Cert:\LocalMachine\My`. Which one do you want?

Comment: Spot on. It works. Thank you very much Dave.  Would you know where "My" is coming from?. Is it documented somewhere? Is it hardcoded? Thanks

Comment: MS storenames have evolved over time, and IME are usually the same, although I _think_ in an 'enterprise' environment (with Domain Controller and Active Directory and such) an admin may be able to change at least some of them. I haven't seen anything much better than https://serverfault.com/questions/416914/how-to-find-out-the-valid-store-names-for-certutil and the 2 MS links differ from each other and my machines, but (as shown there) you can list the names on your machine with powershell `get-childitem` or alias `ls`.